# Via onclick call onserverclick in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have code:

```
<a id="saveAll" href="#" runat="server" OnServerClick="DownloadAll" onclick="return Validation();">Save All</a>

<a id="saveItem" href="#" onclick="CallSaveAll()">Save Item</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validation() {
       return true;
    }

    function CallSaveAll(){
       $("#saveAll").trigger("click");
    }
</script>
```

When I'm debugging after click on "Save All" -> I go to Validation() and after that to DownloadAll() which is server method as I expected.

But when I click on "Save Item" -> I go to Validation() but not to server method DownloadAll(). I don't know how to call server method via jQuery trigger. I know how to call server method via ajax. But with ajax not working my other behaviour. I need only simulate click on "Save All" and go to server method.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't also bind `OnServerClick="DownloadAll"` to `#saveItem`?

Comment: Yes I'm generating Save Item dynamicly with jQuery something like: item = "<a href=\"#messageItemId=" + items[i]["Id"] + "\" onclick=\"SaveItemHandler(this, event)\" runat=\"server\" OnServerClick=\"DownloadAll\">Save Item</a>"; But after that is in function only onclick not OnServerClick

Comment: That's because you're mixing server side and client side code. `runat="server"` attribute is parsed on the server side, and creating it on the client won't help you at all.

Comment: Yes I know that's why I would like to do only item = "<a href=\"#messageItemId=" + items[i]["Id"] + "\" onclick=\"SaveItemHandler(this, event)\">Save Item</a>"; and when I fire SaveItemHandler method I would like to fire Save All with jQuery as I mention above.

Comment: So what I just want know is if I can fire via other element server method OnServerClick which is on another element using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

1. include jquery.simulate.js you can download [here >>](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js)
2. In function call:

`$("#saveAll").simulate("click");`

instead of

```
$("#saveAll").trigger("click");
```